# Facebook interview: Implement readline function

Tags: c, algorithm

The question is

> Implement a function `char* readLine();` which returns single lines from
>   a buffer. To read the buffer, you can makes use of a function int
>   `read(char* buf, int len)` which fills buf with upto len chars and
>   returns the actual number of chars filled in. Function readLine can be
>   called as many times as desired. If there is no valid data or newline
>   terminated string available, it must block. In order to block, it can
>   use read function which in turn will block when it doesn't have
>   anything to fill the buf.

I don't know how to proceed and what kind of approach is expected.
I could not understand what the interviewer expects here. I just need direction to move ahead and not the exact function.

Comment: OP wants to know how to implement extended functionality given the base functionality. I believe that the question is not too localized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allocate an appropriately sized buffers.

If you don't have characters in your read buffer, read in a new chunk.

If the next character from the read buffer is a newline, return the result buffer.

If the result buffer is full, bug out and whine about lines being too long.

Otherwise, add the next character from the read buffer into the result buffer.

**NOTE:** The answer to the question as asked is a security issue waiting to happen, and also a potential memory leak.